# Update TextView every second in Android

Tags: android, timer, textview

i want to update my textview every second.
on button click i am calling one method,

```
loopMethod(milli); //suppose milli= 50000 i.e 50 sec.
```

so my `loopMethod(int m)` is as follows:

```
public void loopMethod(int m){
    timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    if(m>=1000){
        try {
            timer.setText(""+m);//timer is a textview
            System.out.println(m);
            m=m-1000;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        loopMethod(m);
    }
}
```

so what i am expecting is, my timer `textview` should print the value of `m` every second.
but i am getting only console output i.e `system.out.println(m)`...
printing value on console working fine...
but its not updating my textview at all

Comment: every time new textview initialize. Put timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText); out of mathod.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
Runnable updater;
void updateTime(final String timeString) {
    timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

    updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer.setText(timeString);
            timerHandler.postDelayed(updater,1000);
        }
    };
    timerHandler.post(updater);
}
```

In this line:

```
 timerHandler.post(updater);
```

time will set for the first time. i.e, updater will execute. After first execution it will be posted after every 1 second time interval. It will update your TextView every one second.

You need to remove it when the activity destroys, else it will leak memory.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   timerHandler.removeCallbacks(updater);
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ajith Pandian... thanx a lots.. its working as i wanted :D

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding.

Comment: but how to stop it? means i want to stop the updating after my timeString>0...to achieve my output i just added timestring-=1000; after timer.setText. and replace the string data type to int. plz help me. i am not familiar with handler

Comment: timerHandler.removeCallbacks(updater); to stop the handler thread. you can use this whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should use RxJava library to do so:

```
Subscription s =
                Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(v -> {
                    // update your ui here
                }, e -> {

                });

        // call when you no longer need an update:
        if (s != null && !s.isUnsubscribed()){
            s.unsubscribe();
            s = null;
        }
```

That's it. Do NOT use .postDelay(), Timer because it is error prone.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for :) many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the Chronometer class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

just use `timer.start();` on the button click

Answer (score 0):

I've added some logics to stop the Timer. If you have any qyestion, ask freely

```
private int m = 0;
private int milliseconds = 1000;

public void loopMethod(int m){
  timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
  Timer t = new Timer();

  //schedule a timer
  t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {      
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
        @Override
        public void run() {
          timer.setText(String.valueOf(m));//avoid using composite string in the setText
          System.out.println(String.valueOf(m));

          //remove from the total the amount of millisecond passed
          m=m-milliseconds;
          if(m <= milliseconds) { //or <= what you want
            //stop the timer repeatitions
            t.cancel();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  //"0" is the amount of time to wait for the timer to start
  //"milliseconds" is the duration
  },0,milliseconds);
}
```

**Add**

For a correct analysis you should add more infos in your question. the problem of not-updating `textview` might be caused by the `setText("" + int)` because it's always better to avoid the `setText` with an int. I edited it with `String.valueOf`, but if it's not working you should add the `xml` and the `onCreate`

Hope this helped

Comment: facing same problem with above code. :(

Comment: @varsha look my "Add" section, we need some more code

Comment: above code gives error: ---android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. ------------but after adding comments to timer.setText it perfectly displays output on console with system.out.println

Comment: i am just taking milliseconds from user and adding as a parameter to loopMethod. and then after clicking on ok button the timer textview should display the decreasing time after every sec. (Just like countdown)

Comment: @varsha check my updated code

Comment: Yes, working :D

Answer (score 0):

Using handler can be used like this

```
TextView timer;
    int m =0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
        Handler handler = new UpdateHandler();

        m = 10;
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 1000);//start after 1000
    }


    class UpdateHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
                timer.setText("Text :" +m);
                m = m-1000;
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 1000); //seng again after 1000
                //add some stop logic
                break; 

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Initialize textview in

```
onCreate
   timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);


public void loopMethod(int m){

 if(m>=1000){
  try {

    System.out.println(m);
    m=m-1000;

    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor c = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
            c.schedule(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer.setText(""+m);//timer is a textview
                      c.shutdownNow();

                }
            }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);





} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
loopMethod(m);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have created timer for seconds.

```
public class TimerForSeconds extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int seconds = 60;
    private TextView tvTimer;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(seconds == 0){
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
            else{
                tvTimer.setText(seconds + "");
                seconds--;
                mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        tvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
}
```

//and also removCallback onDestroy too.